# Is there a way to tell if a Pitom of an Etrog has been broken, or was grown that way?

Tags: how-to, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Is there a way to tell whether the Pitum of an Etrog has been broken off
or whether the Etrog had just grown that way (without a pitum)?

(I just seem to be a little worried about mine, so any advice based on experience and knowledge would be appreciated!)

Comment: They don't actually grow without a pitom, it is just that certain types naturally lose the pitom before the esrog ripens (while it is still on the tree). This is not considered *chaseir*. See [here](http://halachicadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/2008-JO-esrog.pdf) and [here](http://www.esrogheadquarters.com/pdf/WhattolookFor.pdf). As far as hiddur, see [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/10/12/hiddur-of-esrogim/).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** ( I have revised my answer as it was originally a bit misleading)

Some opinions hold that only if the pitam fell off in the early stages of the esrog's growth, does the esrog remain kosher. In such a case:

> If there is an **indentation** at the tip of the Chotem, where the pitam
>   was once attached, this is a clear indication that the pitam fell off
>   in the early stages of the esrog's development, and the esrog is
>   kosher. Another indication that the pitam fell of in the early satges
>   of the the esrog's growth is a *thin groove* that encircles the area of
>   the fallen pitam.

However some  authorities are more lenient, and hold that a pitam that fell off even immediately before the esrog was picked does not render the esrog pasul.

In this case - then the following would be a sign that the pitam naturally fell off and would be kosher:

> A clear indication that the pitam was fully dried while still on the
>   tree is the presence of a **scab** that *fully cover*s the place where the
>   pitam was severed...
>
> If the place of the pitum is only *partially covered* with the scab ,
>   then it must be assumed that it was still partially attached while on
>   the tree , and only fell off later , after the esrog was picked;
>   consequently, the esrog must be considered pasul.

(Source: The four minim - apractical illusrated guide - by R. Avraham Chaim Adess [feldhaim publishers] - pp154-158)

I myself have seen a esrog with a broken pitum - and I can testify to the above. (ie - you don't see a nice clean scab but rather a bumby/jagged surface.

Comment: I'd think that its breaking off just before or after the _esrog_ was detached would have the same look. But what do I know.

Answer (score -4):

The experts say if you can put a hair through the top then it must have fallen off!

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: What does this even mean? Put a hair through what?

Comment: @DoubleAA where the pitum would have been!

Comment: Just to clarify: when you say “fallen-off” you mean it broke after harvest? (i.e. *pasul*). Or, it had “naturally” fallen-off? (i.e. *kosher*). Also, if you happen to have a source for this would be good!

Comment: @Larry sorry y'all, no source!!! just something in know. Dont think it makes a differenece when it fell off!

Comment: @yehuda But if you see the comment from Fred, he seems to suggest there are some that “naturally” lose their pitom. In any case, if it doesn’t make a difference when it fell off, then what is the point of the hair test? I.e. what is it supposed to determine?

Comment: There needs to be some kind of visual aid for this answer, because it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SethJ [comment disagreeing with the need for visual aids, edited for appropriateness]

Comment: Ouch. That was a bit unnecessary. Your answer is vague at best. How would one insert a hair into a solid object? Is the assumption that if it fell off the base of it is softer? That there is a hole? Is this a metaphor? How do you not see that 4 people (besides me) voted this down? How do you not see that 5 people have voted up @doubleaa's comment? I at least tried to offer a suggestion that you include a visual aid. I'm assuming, to your credit, that this answer at least has merit.

Comment: If you cannot accept that many people do not understand what you are saying, I'm sorry, but you should not take offense. Instead, try to improve your answer.